# C++ formatted input: how to 'skip' tokens?

Tags: c++, formatted-input

Suppose I have an input file in this format:

```
VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
```

I'm writing a program that would be interested only in VAL1 and VAL3. In C, if i wanted to 'skip' the second value, I'd do as follows:

```
char VAL1[LENGTH]; char VAL3[LENGTH];
FILE * input_file;
fscanf(input_file, "%s %*s %s", VAL1, VAL3);
```

Meaning, I'd use the "%*s" formatter to make fscanf() read this token and skip it. **How do I do this with C++'s cin?** Is there a similar command? Or do I have to read to a dummy variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just read the token into some variable, but ignore it?

Comment: @Nixuz: please read my comment to Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [C++ String Toolkit Library (StrTk)](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html) has the following solution to your problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include "strtk.hpp"

int main()
{
   struct line_type
   {
      std::string val1;
      std::string val3;
   };

   std::deque<line_type> line_list;

   const std::string file_name = "data.txt";

   strtk::for_each_line(file_name,
                        [&line_list](const std::string& line)
                        {
                           strtk::ignore_token ignore;
                           line_type temp_line;
                           const bool result = strtk::parse(line,
                                                            " ",
                                                            temp_line.val1,
                                                            ignore,
                                                            temp_line.val3);
                           if (!result) return;
                           line_list.push_back(temp_line);
                        });

   return 0;
}
```

More examples can be found [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

There's an `ignore` function available:

```
std::cin << val1;
std::cin.ignore (9999, ' ');
std::cin << val3;
```

The first argument defines the number of characters to skip, the second parameter is the delimiter to stop skipping at.

You could wrap that up in a user-defined manipulator, since it's ugly.

---

Here's the custom manipulator:

```
template <class charT, class traits>
inline std::basic_istream<charT, traits> &
ignoreToken (std::basic_istream<charT, traits> &strm)
{
    strm.ignore (9999, ' ');
    return strm;
}
```

And you could use that like this:

```
cin >> val1 >> ignoreToken >> val3 >> ignoreToken >> val5;
```

(ps -- I didn't compile this, so there maybe a typo).

Comment: This is VERY close to what I want. But is there no way to ignore ANY number of characters (or a whitespace), instead of fixing a really big value?

Comment: Nope. You gotta supply a big number.  Some of the docs I've read  recommend using "std::numerical_limits<int>::max()", but (IMO) that's just silly.

Comment: std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() PS. Its not silly, its defensive programming.

Comment: What is silly is forcing yourself using something that stinks (C++ streams IO) just because it's there. Actually IMO what is really horrible is output formatting, but even input is not that great.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a much easier way with getline(). Just use it to grab the entire line, and then parse out the values in between the tokens (use strtok?)

There are a whole bunch of other issues with getline(), but it should work for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would just read it into a dummy variable. If you do need it eventually, it will be available.

Comment: Of course this is my 'default' choice, but I'm willing to avoid it since there will be many (circa 10) tokens I don't want. Plus, there is also my own curiosity of trying to do the thing in a 'beautiful' way. I kind of refuse to believe that something already present in C wasn't considered in the design of C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
cin.ignore(256, ' ');
```

This will ignore everything up to either 256 characters or a white space.

Edit (formatting and...): alternatives you can do:

```
int a, b;
cin >> a >> b >> b;
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that. Nice! :)

Comment: Creative, but a dummy variable would actually be more clear in this case =)